# How to redirect path with # in react router v4 with browserHistory?(not with hashhistory)

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

Its not a question about how to switch from hashHistory to browserHistory.
When we input http://www.example.com/#post, it will be recognized as http://www.example.com/post in react-router previous version. but this behavior changes in v4.
http://www.example.com/#post will be treated as http://www.example.com/.
What should I do to bring the previous one back?
Its important on my react project static serving. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean to do this by any chance this.props.history.push('/post')

Comment: At v3, ignore # tag and remove it, get the /post route is by default. I don't  think manually push is a good solution.

Comment: redirect is a manual push rite?